# Why not to create your own custom content-type

Tags: javascript, http, backbone.js, http-headers, content-type

I'm using a web service(API) framework that does some magic behind the scene for different content-types requests.

I want to take advantage of that by creating responses like application/verbose+json but the actual content will still be application/json.

I've implemented it, tested it from a jquery.ajax call in chrome and it all works.

Is there a reason this is wrong or might not work in production/long run?

Not relevant to the question but just in case you're wondering about what it's written in:
 - server side: tastypie(python on django)
 - client side: javascript/coffeescript on backbone

Comment: The "v1" suggests that you're using the content type as part of an API versioning scheme. Do you need the server to respond with that content type or just take it as input?

Comment: I've changed it to verbose+json to avoid the 'versioning' talk. I want a custom content-type, is that wrong? and why?

Comment: I might be wary of what browsers might do with it if you're returning data with that content type. Using to when sending data to the sever should be fine though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Custom content-type hasn't raised any issue until now in production, so i'll solve this issue by saying it's safe.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Media Types (what you call content types) form a global space of names. If you use a "custom" name, you risk that there'll be future name collisions.

If you *really* think your custom name is needed, please consider registering it, see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6838 (there are also vendor and personal spaces).

Comment: Can you describe a collision scenario? I think that if a web service tells you to interact with it in a certain way and you do not, don't expect the documented response.

Comment: The point in assigning a name is usually to trigger a certain behavior. Do you want that to happen with somebody else's "verbose+json" as well? What is the problem you are trying to solve by using that name?

Comment: Tastypie is a REST api framework which allows me to create Serializers (classes that are selected depending on the content-type) and work with internal mechanisms of tastypie to load/unload response. What i want to achieve is similar to this: if 'verbose' not in request.GET return stripped(response) But want something more complicated which already is built in the framework